# Ruby: Using the "index" method with "OR"

Tags: ruby

Using the index method, I'm trying to find if a value exists using a certain variable, and if that variable doesn't exist, then try another variable; a little something like this (3rd line below):

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
a.index("b")   #=> 1
a.index("z" or "y" or "x" or "b")   #=> 1
```

..meaning that if "z" is not found in the array, then try "y"; if y is not found, then try x; if x is not found then try b

How would I do that correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TIMTOWTDI. But I prefer using Array#inject.

```
%w(x y z b).inject(nil) { |i, e| i or a.index(e) } #=> 1
```

And there is an another way to do this with more similar to your pseudo-code.

```
class String
  def | other
    ->(e) { self==e || other==e }
  end
end

class Proc
  def | other
    ->(e) { self.call(e) || other==e }
  end
end

a.index(&('x' | 'y' | 'z' | 'b')) #=> 1
```

Comment: Thank you nwn! I really appreciate the great help :) Thanks so much for the clear explanation.

Comment: requires ruby 1.9 for the `->` lambda syntax.

Comment: Fixed a nasty bug in old revision; `%w(x y z).index(&('foo' | 'bar' | 'zzz' | 'b'))` was evaluated to `2`.

Comment: @glenn Yes, But In this case I think you can use this in 1.8.x with replacing `->(){}` with `lambda{}` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your end goal. If you just want to see if `a` contains a `z`, `y`, `x` or `b`, you can do this:

```
(a & %w{z y x b}).length > 0   # gives true if a contains z, y, x and/or b.
```

what we're doing is seeing if there is a *set intersection* where a contains some shared elements with the set of desired quantities, then testing to see if there were any of those elements.